# “No such host” when Azure web app attempts to communicate with Azure database

Tags: sql-server, azure

Now, I have both my App Service and Database deployed in Azure, they are fine. I can browse to the site perfectly and it all seems to function.

Similarly, I've added a firewall rule in Azure to enable me to connect to the database server and query the database from my local SQL Server Management Studio.

Additionally, when I change my local web application (on my Local IIS Express server) to point to the Azure database it also works fine.

However, when I deploy the application I keep getting: **"No such host is known"**:

> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No such host is
>   known.)] I've tried adding the IP address of the App Service to the
>   database server. I've even tried white listing the entire IP address
>   range just to completely discount that and it doesn't work either!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're publishing from Visual Studio, make sure that you don't overwrite with a different remote connection string when deploying.

[image]

Also make sure you allow for Azure Services access.

[image]

Comment: That was it, it was the config overwrite that seemed to be happening (in the publish profile). Thanks very much :)